# Semantic UI React - Center form in segment?

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am trying to center a form group within a segment in semantic-ui-react.

By setting the container `textAlign` to `center`, I am able to get all elements centered *except* the `Form.Group` and the `Form.Input`'s it contains.

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/mgrnjtmj/

Is it possible to center the form group with the props available to semantic-ui-react?

Comment: I would also tag this as css. Somone there could totally guide you on different ways to handle this without using semantic.

Comment: The problem is that some of these ui libraries use the important css tag making it very difficult to get them do do things.

Answer (score 2):

Use `<semanticUIReact.Grid  className="ui segment centered">...` , and you can remove `textAlign='center'` , like the following :

```
<semanticUIReact.Container>
    <semanticUIReact.Grid className="segment centered">
        <semanticUIReact.Form>
            ...
        </semanticUIReact.Form>
    </semanticUIReact.Grid>
</semanticUIReact.Container>
```

Here is a working [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/saadregal/3jfhzf97/3/)

Comment: FYI, I just needed `<Grid centered>`.  Thought we were supposed to use rows and columns but don't need them.